# Motorcycle engine oil decreasing periodically

Tags: engine, motorcycle, oil

Why the oil is decreasing in the engine, I have to refill the oil monthly

Comment: How much do you have to put in each month? This could be normal for that machine, have you checked the handbook or with the garage or the dealer? Is it new or ancient?

Comment: We really need more information about the bike - make, model, age and mileage at a minimum really.

Answer (score 0):

Most motorcycles use oil over time and it's normal, especially as the bike gets miles on it.  You didn't say how much it uses or how many actual miles were ridden, but in 1500 miles a quart isn't bad....you actually need to change your oil in 2500-3000 miles anyway.  Try using synthetic oil (I prefer Amsoil)....you may have better performance with a high grade oil.

Comment: You guys must own Harley's, because normal well engineered motorcycles don't noticeably lose oil. Certainly not a quart a month. If you're adding a quart of oil to your bike every month, then you've got a leak (or POS).

Comment: @JoshCampbell agreed. Even if I was on a 15 year old honda burning a quart of oil a month seems crazy.

Comment: And we don't even know if the engine is _using_ oil, or _dripping it out the bottom of the sump_.